# how do i get the last last group in a regex expression in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I have a string of data from a data base

`[context]=[context desc].[context level].&[data]`

I have a regex written to find the data part that looks like this

```
(.* [.&;^])(?:[^*])([^]]+)
```

This returns three groups how ever i only want the last one.
How do I get just the final group ?

**Edit**

sorry should have been more clear my out puts from `(re-seq #"(.*[.&;^])(?:[^*])([^]]+)" line)`are:

> (["[context]=[context desc].[context level].&[data" "[context]=[context desc].[context level].&" "data"])

all i want on the out is ["data"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the original question:

The individual matches are returned by `re-seq` in the form of vectors, with the full match being the first item of the vector and the groups being the other elements, in order. You can use `peek` to get the final element of a vector (in a particularly fast way):

```
(def s "[context]=[context desc].[context level].&[data]")
(def r #"(.*[.&;^])(?:[^*])([^]]+)") ; tweaked to remove a space

(map peek (re-seq r s))
;= ("data")
```

It may still be a good idea to pick a different regex. For example, if the final `[data]` substring really does occur right at the end of the input string and if it contains no `[` characters, you could use `#"[^\[]+(?=\]$)"`:

```
(re-seq #"[^\[]+(?=\]$)" s)
;= ("data")
```

Comment: Hi what would i have to put in if my string was like this [context]=[context desc].[context level].&[dataKey: data] and i want to find the data key?

Comment: Assuming there is no `:` in `data` and there's a bounded number of spaces between the colon after `dataKey` and the start of `data`, you could use lookbehind: `(re-seq #"(?<=: )\w+(?=\]$)" "[context]=[context desc].[context level].&[dataKey: data]")` evaluates to `("data")`. (There's a single space after the colon in this version of the regex; you could use `{x,y}` to allow between `x` and `y` spaces, but an unbounded number of spaces -- with `*`, say -- won't work.) If there are extra complications, at some point it'll be simpler to just use the grouping constructs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.* [.&;^])(?:[^*])([^]]+)$
```

Use a $ to denote the end of the string your matching your regex on.

**edit** Since you don't supply a full example of the string your matching on, there's the possibility that the end of the string doesn't occur right after your last matching group, in which case you'd need to use a negative look ahead before the $ make sure there's no more capturable data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try simpler regexp:

```
(def s "[context]=[context desc].[context level].&[data]")

user> (re-find #"\.&(.+)" s)
[".&[data]" "[data]"]

user> (last (re-find #"\.&(.+)" s))
"[data]"
```